# AcquireTokenAsync returning null for User.DisplayableId

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I’m developing a Xamarin app that uses Azure AD B2C and I’m having some trouble getting data from any of the providers.
Even though I have LinkedIn, Google, Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter setup as Identity Providers, and they appear to be configured properly, the only data returned is User.IdentityProvider.  Both User.Name and User.DisplayableId are null.  This happens for all of the providers.

Here is my call to AcquireTokenAsync:

```
var result = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, user, UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, Constants.Authority, App.UiParent);
```

I have my application claims selected:

[image]

The login succeeds on every provider, but I don't get email addresses back like I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from a friend, I discovered that while the values in the User field are returned using Azure AD, the response from an Azure AD B2C call populates the IdToken field instead.

A bit more sleuthing turned up this to be a serialized JwtSecurityToken object.  That led me to the following code:

```
var displayableId = ""; // result.User.DisplayableId;
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(result.IdToken);
foreach (var claim in token.Claims)
{
    if (claim.Type == "emails")
    {
        displayableId = claim.Value;
    }
}
```

Now displayableId contains the user's email address.